# Unable to find column value of max index row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

In the popular UM Intro to DS in Py coursera course, I'm having difficulty completing the second question in the Week 2 assignment.  Based on the below df sample:

```
      # Summer  Silver  Bronze  Total  ...  Silver.2  Bronze.2  Combined total   ID
Gold                                   ...
0           13       0       2      2  ...         0         2               2  AFG
5           12       2       8     15  ...         2         8              15  ALG
18          23      24      28     70  ...        24        28              70  ARG
1            5       2       9     12  ...         2         9              12  ARM
3            2       4       5     12  ...         4         5              12  ANZ

[5 rows x 15 columns]
```

The question is as follows:

> #### Question 1
>
> Which country has won the most gold medals in summer games?
>
> *This function should return a single string value.*
>
> The answer is 'USA'

I know this is very rudimentary, but I cannot get it.  Pretty embarrassed but very frustrated.

The below are errors I've encountered.

```
df['Gold'].argmax()
...
KeyError: 'Gold'

df['Gold'].idxmax()
...
KeyError: 'Gold'

max(df.idxmax())
...
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype

df.ID.idxmax()
TypeError: reduction operation 'argmax' not allowed for this dtype
```

This works, but not within a function

```
df['ID'].sort_index(axis=0,ascending=False).iloc[0]
```

I really appreciate any support.

**Update 1**
[One successful attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVIrw.png)
thanks to @Grr! I'm am still very curious as to why other methods are failing

**Update 2**
[Second successful attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZp9k.png) thanks to @alec_djinn, this approach was similar to what I had previously tried but could not figure out.  Thank you!

Comment: What error do you get when returning the final bit of working code inside a function?

Comment: linking error images to the post now

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
df.ID.idxmax()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it didn't work though.  I have linked the error above.

Comment: @trevor.r.sweeney Can you share an example of your `df` that produces such error?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd that that column is your index, but be that as it may you could grab the row where the value of the index is equal to the max of the index and then reference the `ID` column.

```
df[df.index == df.index.max()].ID
```

Your other methods are failing as a result of the `KeyError`. The index name is `Gold`, but `Gold` is not in the column index and this raises the `KeyError`. I.e. `df['Gold']` is not possible when 'Gold' is the index. Instead use `df.index`. You could also reset the index like so.

```
df = df.reset_index()
df

   Gold  # Summer  Silver  Bronze  Total  # Winter  Gold.1  ...  Total.1  # Games  Gold.2  Silver.2  Bronze.2  Combined total   ID
0     0        13       0       2      2         0       0  ...        0       13       0         0         2               2  AFG
1     5        12       2       8     15         3       0  ...        0       15       5         2         8              15  ALG
2    18        23      24      28     70        18       0  ...        0       41      18        24        28              70  ARG
3     1         5       2       9     12         6       0  ...        0       11       1         2         9              12  ARM
4     3         2       4       5     12         0       0  ...        0        2       3         4         5              12  ANZ

[5 rows x 16 columns]
```

Then you can use `df['Gold']` or `df.Gold` as you were attempting before as 'Gold' is now an acceptable key.

```
df.Gold.idxmax()
2
```

In my case its 'ARG' with 18 Gold medals

Comment: I agree, assuming they framed the question like this on purpose? Anyway, it was successful!  Please see my update, thank you for the help.

Comment: I see, makes complete sense. Thanks for the explanation, back to your point I'm not sure why Gold was made the index.  I appreciate the help!!

Comment: Probably to force you to figure out the named index/key discrimitation

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do the following:

```
df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True)
df.head(1)['ID'] #or df.iloc[0]['ID']
```

in a function it would be:

```
def f(df):
    df.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace=True) #you can sort outside the function as well
    return df.iloc[0]['ID']
```

Comment: Got it!  I had tried something similar in the past, but left out ['ID'] I believe.  Please see the update, thank you!